# How to do a layout of 3 column of 3 rows dynamically with flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, layout, flexbox, next.js

I need to do a layout dynamically on nextjs, with 3 columns of 3 rows and so on.
Actually I use flexbox. Is it possible to do this with flexbox, Reactbootstrap or some CSS only ?

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your problem? Why not use css-grid? Or use column flexbox inside a parent row flexbox.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with CSS grid. To precise my problem : I have some shows an a list of gigs that the webmaster needs to be able to add day by day. To respect the design, I want to have a repetition of 3 rows and 3 columns ... I don't know if it's more clear

Comment: You can use columns:3 on parent wrapper

Answer (score 1):

To achieve the basic 3x3 shape with auto-wrapping I would use a simple css flexbox using:

- `flex-direction: column`
- `flexwrap: wrap`
- (and limit the height to decide where items start wrapping)
  Then to achieve the multiple 3x3's I think there's no way to do it in plain css, but you can simply devide the list of items into groups of 9 using js (react side) and render the 3x3 as multiple times as I said before.

For more information on flexbox, I'd recommend the css-tricks article on it:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I'll try that. I try to understand the CSS grid article on css-tricks also. Thank you